# Upload image into FTP through HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload images into my FTP images folder.
How should I go about doing it?

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
 {
 $filename=  $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
 if ((($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] ==       "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/png")  || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))&& ($_FILES["imgfile"]["size"] < 9999999999))
 {
  if(file_exists($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]))
 {
 echo "File name exists.";
 }
 else
 {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"images/$filename");
 echo "Upload Successful . <a href='images/$filename'>Click here</a> to view the         uploaded image";
}
}
 else
 {
 echo "invalid file.";
 }
 }
 else
 {
 ?>
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 File name:<input type="file" name="imgfile"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
 </form>
```

Comment: What is your real question exactly? You want a script that uploads your image? That's not really what SO is for i guess.

Comment: I want it to upload into my FTP images folder. The code I have above "images/$filename" does not goes into the folder

Comment: Read the manual [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will check extension:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name']))
{
    $fileExtension = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
    $file_name = pathinfo($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]);
    $extension = strtolower($file_name['extension']);
    if(!in_array($extension, $fileExtension))
    {
        $error .= "<span class='error'>invalid file format !</span><br>";
    }
}
```

.

And here is how you will upload if no errors are found:

```
$tmp_file = '';       
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name']))
{
    $file_name = pathinfo($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]);
    $extension = strtolower($file_name['extension']);
    $tmp_file = substr($file_name['filename'], 0, 50).'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    $uploaddir = 'user_image/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$tmp_file;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    //list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadfile);

    $fileType = $_FILES['imgfile']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['imgfile']['size'];
}
```